# URI for local resources

Tags: java, uri

In Java can I create a URI for a file located locally in the hard drive? If so, how should it be constructed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look at [File documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

File has a constructor, which takes URI as a parameter, and it also has method `toURI()` if you want to get URI from existing file. You can play with that to understand how the things should be done.

You can also read about [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (it's not a java term). There is an example in Wikipedia:

> file:///home/username/RomeoAndJuliet.pdf

Answer (score 10):

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///filename.txt");
```

If you're using Windows:

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///C:/fun/filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///C:/other/mydir/myfile.txt");
```

Comment: I have used the following code
    String uri = "file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Ant/Desktop/travel.owl";

but it gives me error:
SEVERE: Exception caught -- java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 20: file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Ant/Desktop/travel.owl

Any idea?

Comment: @Anto: I think it should be encoded url (i.e. without whitespaces)

Comment: do I have to replace white spaces with some symbol or do I have to just cut the white spaces?

Comment: @Anto: try URLEncoder http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html