# How to force Java to use Unix file separators on Windows?

Tags: java

I have a simple code

```
String staticDir = f.getCanonicalPath() + "/src/main/webapp/static/";
```

On Windows it will return for me "C:\Temp/src/main/webapp/static/".

How to force Java to use "/" instead of "\"?

I have tried

```
System.setProperty("file.separator", "/");
String staticDir = f.getCanonicalPath() + "/src/main/webapp/static/";
```

but it doesn't solved issue for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem

Comment: whys is this a problem for you? does it break something?

Comment: Yeah, I have another lib, that will process that path. And that function only accepts "/" separators.

Comment: I think you should try to get `file:///c:/` URI instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466408/2308683

Comment: Are you in fact trying to create a URI?  Because if you are, changing the file separator to `/` is not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was a bug in the library, that I use - https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/111 .

That's why all suggested solution didn't solved issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the path separator with the expected one:

```
String dir = f.getCanonicalPath().replace(System.getProperty("file.separator"), "/")
             + "/src/main/webapp/static/";
```

If you can, favor Java 7+'s `java.nio.file.Path`. There, the notion of path separator disappears until you call `toString()`. But very few libraries use this and still use `File` or even, worse, `String`.

If the library you're using still does it by the mean of strings, it probably means they're splitting manually on `/`. Maybe it's time to tell them to upgrade?

Comment: That's YUICompressor ( https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor ) - it is not updated for a long time...

Comment: That bug is not fixed from 2013 ))) https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/111