# Downloading File from a server

Tags: java, file, download, fileinputstream

I'm trying to download a file which I have on a server.
If I run my application on local everything works properly and I can download the file. Also, I can download the file from a browser or Windows File explorer.
However, when I upload my application to my server, I can't get the file.

```
try {
        uri = "\\DEVDOCSERVER\DOCUMENTS\sample.xml";
        if(uri.contains(".") ) {

            String extension = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("."));

            File file = new File(uri);

            if(file!=null)
                logger.error("file size: " + file.length());

            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();  

            String fileName = getFileName(uri);
            logger.error("file name: " + fileName);


            String contentType = "application/octet-stream";

            response.setContentType(contentType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+fileName);  
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length()); 
            ServletOutputStream out = null;  
            try {  

                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);  
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
                out = response.getOutputStream();  
                int i = 0;  
                while ((i = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {  
                    out.write(buffer);  
                    out.flush();  
                }  

                if(input!=null)
                    logger.error("file input: " + input.toString());
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();  
            } catch (IOException err) { 
                err.printStackTrace();  
            } finally {  
                try {  
                    if (out != null) {  
                        out.close();  
                    }  
                } catch (IOException err) {  
                    err.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }  
        } 

    } catch (InternacionalizacionFwException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I check log, I get next error: (No such file or directory) and the file size is 0

Comment: What is the path to your server ? Did you change your path ?

Comment: I have two servers, one for my app and another for documents, but there are in the same network

Comment: See this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466369/uri-for-local-resources

Comment: File on another server is not local resource. Perhaps you can create a simlink and then treat the file as local file.

Comment: But I'm not in documents server so I can't access like  "file:///C:/f..."

Comment: Please mind that `\ ` is an escape character in Java string literal.  Which means `"\\DEVDOCSERVER\DOCUMENTS\sample.xml";` is going to, for example, give you only one backslash in beginning.  And, I couldn't even compile with illegal escape (`\s` etc) in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Which Server - Linux, Windows etc. In Linux env its path should be set to forward slash e.g /opt/something/yourfile.  Also please log the file path to know in run time location for file you are looking which will help you understand the cause of issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working in Windows computer and my server is Linux, so I have to change the url when I upload

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved my problem changing the file path depending if I'm working on Windows or Linux.
I also moved the file to another folder because it seemed that I hadn't permissions in the folder I was.
And I had to change the way I was reading the file, because I was getting and error "Error: Network Error" when I was downloading file
Now I'm reading with apache commons:

```
 FileUtils.copyFile(file, response.getOutputStream());
```